# Entity Framework generate sql with column that does not exist in database or code first model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first, hybrid

I have a situation where the entity framework is adding a contract_id column to a contract model and the column does not exist as a property on C# model and it does not exist in the database either. I have already combed the database and the solution for any reference to 'contract_id' and I am scratching my head for this one.

```
[Export(typeof(IModel))]
[Grid.GridNavigator(cloneToTop = true, add = true, del = true, refresh = true, refreshstate = Grid.RefreshState.current, addfunc = "$.modules.grids.contract.add")]
[Grid.Events(serializeGridData = "$.modules.grids.common.serialize")]
public class Contract
    : Model
    , ILogicalDelete
{
    #region properties
    [Key]
    [Grid.Column("ContractID", TypeName = "int", Label = "Contract ID", Width = 75, VisibleTo = new Type[] { typeof(Contract) })]
    [Grid.Search(SearchOperators.equal)]
    [Grid.Controls.Hidden]
    public override int ID { get { return base.ID; } set { base.ID = value; } }

    [Grid.Column("CorrelationID", Hidden = true)]
    [Grid.Controls.Hidden]
    public Guid? CorrelationID { get; set; }

    //[Grid.Column("StatusID", ModelNavigation = "Status", HiddenFromNavigation = true)]
    //[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    //public int StatusID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Grid.Column("ContractDesc", TypeName = "varchar", Label = "Description")]
    [Grid.Search(SearchOperators.begins_with | SearchOperators.contains | SearchOperators.ends_with)]
    [Grid.Controls.CustomEditable(Grid.ControlType.autocomplete, Url = "/api/contractservice/list?name=contract&column=ContractDesc&_type={0}", KeyField = "ID", TextField = "ContractDesc", ForReferenceUse = true)]
    public string ContractDesc { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Grid.Column("ContractType", TypeName = "varchar", Label = "Type", VisibleTo = new Type[] { typeof(Contract) }, HiddenFromNavigation = true)]
    [Grid.Search(Grid.SearchType.select, url = "/api/contractservice/list?name=ContractType", build = "$.services.grid.ctrls.select.build")]
    //[Grid.Controls.Select(Url = "/api/contractservice/list?name=ContractType", BuildSelect = "$.services.grid.ctrls.select.build")]
    public string ContractType { get; set; }

    [Grid.Column("Audited", TypeName = "bit", FormatterType = Grid.FormatterType.checkbox, Alignment = Grid.Position.center, Width = 50, HiddenFromNavigation = true)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(Grid.Serialization.BooleanConverter))]
    public bool Audited { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    [Grid.Column("Comment", TypeName = "varchar", HiddenFromNavigation = true)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [Grid.Column("CreatedOn", TypeName = "date", Label = "Created On", FormatterType = Grid.FormatterType.date, Alignment = Grid.Position.center, Width = 75, Hidden = true, HiddenFromNavigation = true)]
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [Grid.Column("IsDeleted", TypeName = "bit", Hidden = true, Default = false, HiddenFromNavigation = true)]
    public bool is_deleted { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region constructor
    public Contract()
    {
        Members = new HashSet<ContractMember>();
        PricingTiers = new HashSet<TierMatrix>();
        Terms = new HashSet<ContractDetail>();
    }
    #endregion

    //Status _status = null;

    //public virtual Status Status { get { return _status; } set { StatusID = value.IsNotNull(oObject => oObject.ID, StatusID); _status = value; } }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ContractMember> Members { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractMemberDetail> MemberDetails { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<TierMatrix> PricingTiers { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ContractDetail> Terms { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
class ContractConfiguration
    : EntityTypeConfiguration<Models.Contract>
{
    internal ContractConfiguration(string table, string schema = "dbo")
    {
        ToTable(table, schema);

        HasKey(Model => Model.ID);

        Property(Model => Model.ID)
            .HasColumnName("ContractID")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(Model => Model.ContractDesc)
            .HasColumnName("ContractDesc")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsOptional()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        Property(Model => Model.ContractType)
            .HasColumnName("ContractType")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        Property(Model => Model.Audited)
            .HasColumnName("Audited")
            .HasColumnType("bit")
            .IsRequired();

        Property(Model => Model.Comment)
            .HasColumnName("Comment")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsOptional()
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        Property(Model => Model.CreatedOn)
            .HasColumnName("CreatedOn")
            .HasColumnType("smalldatetime")
            .IsRequired();

        Property(Model => Model.CorrelationID)
            .HasColumnName("CorrelationID")
            .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier")
            .IsOptional();

        Property(Model => Model.is_deleted)
            .HasColumnName("IsDeleted")
            .HasColumnType("bit")
            .IsRequired();

        HasMany(Model => Model.Members)
           .WithRequired(Model => Model.Contract);

        HasMany(Model => Model.PricingTiers)
            .WithRequired(Model => Model.Contract);

        HasMany(Model => Model.Terms)
            .WithRequired(Model => Model.Contract);
    }
}
```

Model Builder:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Configurations.ContractConfiguration("Contract", Common.Schema.contract_management));
    }
```

watching this variable:
Context().Set(typeof(Models.Contract)).ToString()

generates the following:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ContractID] AS [ContractID], 
[Extent1].[CorrelationID] AS [CorrelationID], 
[Extent1].[ContractDesc] AS [ContractDesc], 
[Extent1].[ContractType] AS [ContractType], 
[Extent1].[Audited] AS [Audited], 
[Extent1].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
[Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
[Extent1].[Contract_ID] AS [Contract_ID] //<--- this is what does not belong
FROM [cm].[Contract] AS [Extent1]
```

I have reviewed the database drop and create scripts for the table and Contract_ID does not appear in them. I have reviewed all the foreign keys related to this table and made sure they are ContractID not Contract_ID. the text Contract_ID appears no where in the solutions code base either. we also do not have any triggers on this database table.

I am running out of places to check in the code. I am contemplating a band aid that will create a computed column called Contract_ID that regurgitates the primary key value. If anyone can give me an idea on where to look that would be awesome.

Comment: Have you tried to run a select query over it? Check if it returns the same values as ContractID. Perhaps it has something to do with base model class, try to do the same (Context().Set.ToString()) for other entities that inherit from it, and see if similar column returns.

Comment: I have looked at other entities that inherit the same base model and they do not have the extra column 'Contract_ID'.

Comment: So they don't have any extra columns at all?

Comment: something to add since I played around with changing the name of the model in the C# code. I changed the class name to ContractNew and the column that does not belong changed to "ContractNew_ID". does this narrow done what the entity framework is doing. maybe does the framework think that a key column is missing and it is overthinking it.

Comment: The Attribute Grid.ColumnAttribute inherits from Annotations.ColumnAttribute

Comment: okay I gave up and renamed the primary key on the database to Contract_ID and updated the mapping. the reason that did not work is because now the column is named "Contract_ID1". does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I finally rebuilt the C# model from scratch and I have found the cause of the extra column and problem was in the foreign key mappings

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ContractMember> Members { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ContractMemberDetail> MemberDetails { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<TierMatrix> PricingTiers { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ContractDetail> Terms { get; set; }
```

located on the C# model.

turns out mapping this from the perspective of the contract model.

```
        HasMany(Model => Model.Members)
           .WithRequired(Model => Model.Contract);

        HasMany(Model => Model.MemberDetails)
           .WithOptional(Model => Model.Contract);

        HasMany(Model => Model.PricingTiers)
            .WithRequired(Model => Model.Contract);

        HasMany(Model => Model.Terms)
            .WithRequired(Model => Model.Contract);
```

removes the need from mapping collections from perspective of these four models. in fact including the foreign key mappings on the  Member, MemberDetails, PricingTiers and Terms. did something to EF where the framework logic decided that it needed Contract_ID column on the contract model when none was found.